# How to fix end of file error after adding image scroller from database in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to have an image scroller with images that are populated from a database. I am querying my db for an array of articles section which works fine. The issue is that when I add the div with id scroller, PHPStorm shows an error that it expects an endif at the end of the file. If I remove the scroller div everything works fine. I did the same that I did for the article section below it so I don't understand what the issue is. Here's the pertinent code in my  section:

```
    <body>

    <div id="scroller" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="innerScrollArea">
            <?php
            include 'DB.php';
            $db = new DB();
            $feats = $db->getRows('products',array('order_by'=>'prod_id DESC LIMIT 5'));
            if(!empty($feats)): $amount = 0; foreach($feats as $feat): $amount++;
            ?>
            <ul>

                <li><img src='<?php echo $feats['prod_feat']; ?>' width="600" height="400" /></li>

            </ul>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-container" >

            <div class="container object">

                <div id="main-container-image">
                    <!--result data-->
                    <section class="work" id="userData">
                        <?php
                            include 'DB.php';
                            $db = new DB();
                            $users = $db->getRows('products',array('order_by'=>'prod_id DESC'));
                            if(!empty($users)): $count = 0; foreach($users as $user): $count++;
                        ?>
                        <figure class="white">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editUser('<?php echo $user['prod_id']; ?>')">
                                <img src='<?php echo $user['prod_image']; ?>' alt="" />
                                <dl>
                                    <dt><?php echo '#'.$count; ?></dt>
                                    <dd><?php echo $user['prod_name']; ?></dd>
                                </dl>
                            </a>
                            <div id="wrapper-part-info">
                                    <div class="part-info-image"><img src='<?php echo $user['prod_desc']; ?>' alt="" width="28" height="28"/></div>
                                    <p id="part-info"><span class="stars"><?php echo $user['prod_rating']; ?></span></p>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <?php endforeach; else: ?>
                        <figure><dt colspan="5">No product(s) found......</dt></figure>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing an `endif;` for the first `if`-statement, after the `endforeach;`.

Comment: You're also using `$user['prod_feat']` in the first loop, while iterating through `$feats`, so you should get an _"Undefined variable"_-notice there. You need to be observant when copy/pasting code snippets.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry. Bit tired. That was a typo. I'll fix it.